# onchange event not accepting my javascript code

Tags: javascript, onchange

I have two text input for the user to type numbers, and I would like the page to output the total of these two numbers in another text input

```html
<input id="attendance_1" onchange="parseInt(document.getElementById('attendance_output').value) += parseInt(this.value);" type="text" name="attendance_1" value="" />

<input id="attendance_2" onchange="parseInt(document.getElementById('attendance_output').value) += parseInt(this.value);" type="text" name="attendance_2" value="" />

// The results of adding the two text values should go here
<input id="attendance_output" type="text" value="" />
```

I get the error:

```js
ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
```

Comment: [Try](https://jsfiddle.net/q4cv6qdt/3/) this one mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest putting the code of your onchange in a function and just calling that function onclick. It makes things way more easy to debug.

Example

```
function addValue(field) {
    parseInt(document.getElementById('attendance_output').value) += parseInt(field.value);
}

<input id="attendance_1" onchange="addValue(this)" type="text" name="attendance_1" value="" />

<input id="attendance_2" onchange="parseInt(document.getElementById('attendance_output').value) += parseInt(this.value);" type="text" name="attendance_2" value="" />

// The results of adding the two text values should go here
<input id="attendance_output" type="text" value="" />
```

But the problem is, that your calculation is not assigned to anything. You take the field value, parse it and try to and a value to the parse result.

I guess you want to add that value to the field value and assign it?!

```
function addValue(field) {
    var val = parseInt(document.getElementById('attendance_output').value);
    val += parseInt(field.value);
    document.getElementById('attendance_output').value = val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but the the output field says "NaN"

Comment: If one of the fields does not have a valid number as current value, the result is NaN. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. it should work.
your code is not working because += sign in expression.

```html
<input id="attendance_1" onchange="document.getElementById('attendance_output').value=parseInt(document.getElementById('attendance_output').value) + parseInt(this.value);" type="text" name="attendance_1" value="" />

<input id="attendance_2" onchange="document.getElementById('attendance_output').value=parseInt(document.getElementById('attendance_output').value) + parseInt(this.value);" type="text" name="attendance_2" value="" />

// The results of adding the two text values should go here
<input id="attendance_output" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: I tried that before I came here, same thing. It says in the result text "NaN"

Answer (score 1):

So this is really basic JS with typechecks

```
function addValue(field) {
    parseInt(document.getElementById('attendance_output').value) += parseInt(field.value);
}

<input id="attendance_1" onchange="addValue(this)" type="text" name="attendance_1" value="" />

<input id="attendance_2" onchange="parseInt(document.getElementById('attendance_output').value) += parseInt(this.value);" type="text" name="attendance_2" value="" />

// The results of adding the two text values should go here
<input id="attendance_output" type="text" value="" />
```

But the problem is, that your calculation is not assigned to anything. You take the field value, parse it and try to and a value to the parse result.

I guess you want to add that value to the field value and assign it?!

```
function addValue(field) {
    var oVal = parseInt(document.getElementById('attendance_output').value);
    var iVal = parseInt(field.value);

    if(!oVal || Number.isNaN(oVal)) {
        oVal = 0;
    }

    if(!iVal || Number.isNaN(iVal)) {
        iVal = 0;
    }

    oVal = oVal + iVal;

    document.getElementById('attendance_output').value = oVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. :) it will not work properly if the user input string, so i think it should have validation.

```
function addValue() {
var num1 = document.getElementById('attendance_1').value;
var num2 = document.getElementById('attendance_2').value;
if (num1 === ''){
    num1 = 0;
}
if(num2 === ''){
    num2 = 0;
}

    var sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
  document.getElementById('attendance_output').value = sum;

}
```

you can make the textbox accept only numbers, by using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#attendance_1, #attendance_2").keydown(function (e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
        (e.keyCode == 65 && ( e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true ) ) ||
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
             return;
    }
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code inside

```
onchange="document.getElementById('attendance_output').value=+document.getElementById('attendance_output').value+ +this.value"
```

Hope it will be useful for you :)

Answer (score 1):

This may be an option. I removed the inline JS completely. Went from `onchange` to an `oninput` handler, which will only do the calculation if the values given are actually numbers not strings.

```js
var inpt = document.querySelectorAll('.attendance');
var out = document.getElementById('attendance_output');

var onInput = function(e) {
  if(/\d/.test(this.value)) {
    var sum = [].slice.call(inpt).reduce(function(a, b) {
      if (a.value.length && b.value.length) {
        return +a.value + +b.value;
      } else {
        return +a.value || +b.value;
      }
    })
    out.value = sum || this.value;
  } else {
    out.value = "";
  }
}

inpt.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('input', onInput, false)
})
```

```html
<input class="attendance" type="text" name="attendance_1" value="" /> <span>+</span>
<input class="attendance" type="text" name="attendance_2" value="" />

<br><br>
<input id="attendance_output" type="text" value="" disabled />
```